# Modified active contour method in image processing

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image

I have images like this:

```
from skimage.segmentation import inverse_gaussian_gradient
from skimage.filters import meijering
from skimage import color
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
import cv2

# Load image, convert RGB to GRAY and then to float64
original = color.rgb2gray(skimage.io.imread("stack.jpg"))
image = skimage.img_as_float64(original)
```

[image: Original image]

And I want to get result like this (each worm has one unique color and is correctly recognized at intersections, ...):
[image: Result image]

I tried Gaussian gradient:

```
# Make Gaussian gradient of image
gradient = inverse_gaussian_gradient(image)
gradient = gradient - np.amin(gradient)
gradient = gradient * (1 / np.amax(gradient))
gradient = np.uint8(gradient * 255)
```

[image: Gaussian gradient]

I also tried ridge detector on raw image and then also on gradient:

```
# Get ridges
ridge = meijering(gradient, sigmas=[1], mode='reflect', black_ridges=0)
ridge = np.uint8(ridge * 255)
```

[image: Ridge detector on raw image]
[image: Ridge detector on gradient image]

And of course I tried Canny, too:

```
# Get edges
edges = feature.canny(image, sigma=3)
edges = np.uint8(edges * 255)
```

[image: Canny]

I want to use some or all of these filters to find all worms in image (join separated curves from filters, choose good curve path for each worm at intersections, ...). I think filters are doing pretty good job - I want to program modified [active contour model](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_active_contours.html) that combines some features from them, but I do not know, how to program it. Active contour model can be parametrized by:

- Worm's length (long white smooth curve in ridge detector)
- Worm's smoothness - each curve can be approximated as smooth curve (spline/Bezier/..)
- Worm's symmetry - it has always two identical mirrored curves at the edge (use somehow two long black spaces along long white curve in gradient)
- Worm's same size except for its ends

Anybody, please, know, how to program it in Python/C++?

Comment: Is this helpful to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129595/how-can-i-detect-an-object-in-image-frame-using-opencv

Comment: You're aware that this has been done before, right? I recommend that you read the literature first before you try to reinvent the wheel. If you find existing methods are not good enough, then you can always try to improve on them or invent a totally new approach. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=detecting+c+elegans+image&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard Thank you, but it's a completely different problem

Comment: @CrisLuengo Of course I know that. I wanted to apply the active contour method to an example to make it clear what I was talking about.